# Prevent Resizing of Image Inside a Table (Table is in inside another Cell)

Tags: html, laravel, image, html-table

my app is able to make PDF documents and I have issues displaying multiple images in a cell.

```
    <td class="table-cell" style="vertical-align: top;">
        <table class="photo">
            <tr>
                @forelse ($item->photos as $photo)
                <td class="inline-block">
                    <img src="{{HelpMe::photo_tumbnail_200($photo->filepath)}}">
                </td>
                @empty
                Item does not have any photo.
                @endforelse
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
```

1. Images i send to my view is already at needed sizes, I dont want them to be resized.
2. Above code fits all all images into one row.

So what happens is that if I have 15 images in that loop, it will put 15 resized images right next to each other in one row.  I dont want the table to resize the images, when space runs out on that row, I want it to jump to the next row.

How could i make this happen?

Comment: Please add a minimal reproducible  example in your question to speed up the solving part.

Answer (score 0):

you can add `<table class="photo flex flex-wrap -mb-4">` as you can see [here](https://tailwindcss.com/components/grids/#wrapping-columns)

```
       <td class="table-cell" style="vertical-align: top;">
            <table class="photo flex flex-wrap -mb-4">
                <tr class="w-1/3 mb-4 bg-gray-400 h-12">
                    @forelse ($item->photos as $photo)

                        <img src="{{HelpMe::photo_tumbnail_200($photo->filepath)}}">

                    </td>
                    @empty
                    Item does not have any photo.
                    @endforelse
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
```

Comment: I use tailwind, but no luck. What did you think it would do?

Comment: try this add <br> tag after <img> tag